# Using CIS Benchmarks with openscap

Tags: centos, security, openscap

I am trying to get CIS Centos 6 benchmarks running with openscap. But it does not work. I am calling it like this:

```
oscap oval eval  /var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml
```

which produces tons of output like

```
File '/var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml' line 8464: Element '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}object_component': No match found for key-sequence ['oval:org.cisecurity.benchmarks.o_centos_centos:obj:10389'] of keyref '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}objectKeyRef'.
File '/var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml' line 8470: Element '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}object_component': No match found for key-sequence ['oval:org.cisecurity.benchmarks.o_centos_centos:obj:10391'] of keyref '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}objectKeyRef'.
File '/var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml' line 8476: Element '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}object_component': No match found for key-sequence ['oval:org.cisecurity.benchmarks.o_centos_centos:obj:10391'] of keyref '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}objectKeyRef'.
File '/var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml' line 8482: Element '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}object_component': No match found for key-sequence ['oval:org.cisecurity.benchmarks.o_centos_centos:obj:10393'] of keyref '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}objectKeyRef'.
File '/var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml' line 8488: Element '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}object_component': No match found for key-sequence ['oval:org.cisecurity.benchmarks.o_centos_centos:obj:10393'] of keyref '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}objectKeyRef'.
File '/var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml' line 8494: Element '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}object_component': No match found for key-sequence ['oval:org.cisecurity.benchmarks.o_centos_centos:obj:10395'] of keyref '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}objectKeyRef'.
File '/var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml' line 8500: Element '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}object_component': No match found for key-sequence ['oval:org.cisecurity.benchmarks.o_centos_centos:obj:10395'] of keyref '{http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5}objectKeyRef'.
OpenSCAP Error: Invalid OVAL Definition (5.11) content in /var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml. [oscap_source.c:268]
```

I tried getting around this with the `--skip-valid`, but that does not help either:

```
oscap oval eval --skip-valid /var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml 
OpenSCAP Error: Unknown test type oval:org.cisecurity.benchmarks.o_centos_centos:tst:10003. [oval_test.c:402]
Failed to import the OVAL Definitions from '/var/tmp/cis-cat-full/benchmarks/CIS_CentOS_Linux_6_Benchmark_v2.0.1-oval.xml'. [oval_session.c:238]
```

Has anyone experience running CIS benchmarks with openscap, and if so, how does this work?

Answer (score 2):

I am an OpenSCAP developer. We use the official XML Schemas provided by MITRE and CIS. From the messages it looks like the OVAL file you got is not a valid OVAL 5.11 file.

You could work around it by using --skip-valid but a better solution is to report this issue to CIS and get it fixed.

Comment: That sure sounds like a reasonable explanation. I tried the `--skip-valid` flag, but that does not help (see my updated post). Of course, the CIS oval files claim to be valid OVAL 5.11 - is there a way I can check that claim other then with oscap?

Comment: Oh, and I contacted CIS about this, but did not get any response, which is why I came here :/

Answer (score 0):

Openscap 1.3.4 seems to not having AIX interim_fix capability which is causing to not to run the CIS unix.xml oval file.

Adding below lines and building the source code will fix the issue and ignore interim_fix tests

file : src/oval_enumerations.c

```
{OVAL_AIX_INTERIM_FIX, "interim_fix"},
{OVAL_AIX_NO, "no"},
```